# large arrays with lots of null entries

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program in Java that currently has this line:

```
double[][][][][][][][][][][] array = new double[20][10][9][8][5][4][4][3][3][3][2];
```

However, the majority of these entries will remain as null. Is there an alternative to using an array that will only allocate memory for each entry when the entry is changed from being null?

Comment: why your array look like this, what is your logic!

Comment: ... It's been a while since I last wrote Java; however, isn't that an 11 dimensional array? Why are you using so many dimensions?

Comment: An array of 11 dimensions? Wow. I can barely deal with 3, and can't even imagine any real problem needing that. Maybe you should think about defining named abstractions, and start using classes.

Comment: That is an awfully difficult array to manage.

Comment: Unless it's changed since I last learned Java Arrays, arrays are not dynamic in the way you want them to be. Your declaration of the array will allocate the memory.

Comment: The array is 11 dimensional because each entry refers to a point in 10 dimensional space with 2 parameters (colour and intensity)

Comment: You are right in the sense of no real problem needs this the problem is from pure Mathematics

Comment: To expand on everyone's concerns, each dimension in the array adds a ton more complexity for both the programmer and the system. The system will require a ton more memory to handle the extra dimensions. The most common dimensions are 1 and 2. 2 is to represent a 2-D grid. 3 might be appear for a 3D grid. Anything higher is extremely unlikely, and if they appear it's very probable that your system has major design flaws.

Comment: You could use ArrayLists, or plain Vectors - you would save some memory, but add overhead. How many of those structures do you have? Perhaps take a look at https://nd4j.org/ The library is quite good.

Comment: @GAker What is a 10-dimensional space? Is that even imaginable? Why can't you use a 3-dimensionsal space (X, Y, Z)?

Comment: @GAker so you can at least reduce that to 10 dimensions, and store Parameter objects, having a field color and a field intensity. Do the same exercise with the other dimensions, and you'll have something easier to figure out.

Comment: Why is everyone up in arms about this data structure. If I did the math right, it will only have 62 million entries. No big deal. No need to optimize because it is sparsely populated.

Comment: @GAker Also I don't know what your program is post to do; but, based on what you said so far... You want to keep track of a color and intensity in a 3space. You could actually make this a single `Array<MyObject>`. Where `MyObject` would holds values for `X`, `Y`, `Z` coordinates (3d-space), color, and intensity values.

Comment: @Rob the main problem is not performance or memory. the main problem is readability and understandability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use a map instead of an array and it will only allocate for each entry. Something like:

```
public class Key { double d1,d2,d2...d11; (constructor, equals, comparable (if want sorted), hash etc) }

Map<Key, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();

Key key = new Key(20, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2);
map.put(key, 1.0);
```

Comment: Yes something like this is precisely what I was looking for

Comment: yep, if arrays will have alot of "gaps" in their elements, `SparseArray` would be the place to go.